# How do I manage multiple definitions of the same abbreviation?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using `glossaries`, and I have a separate spreadsheet that I use to maintain a global list of abbreviations, terms, and definitions, used across multiple documents. The spreadsheet then gives me all the `newglossaryentry` and `newacronym` code to paste into my a separate `glossary.tex` file, which is then included in the compilation. That all works fine.

The issue comes when I have the same abbreviation with two different meanings in the same document. For example, "TMS" can mean "Train Management System", and also "Traffic Management System". This occurs due to multiple sources of information contributing to the document. I cannot dictate that only one meaning is correct, therefore I must support them both.
Another example is "EMP" meaning "Engineering Management Plan", and "Environmental Mgt Plan". Both valid, both used by different groups, both need to be defined in the glossary.

It's true that it would be very nice if all abbreviations were unique and unambiguous, but they're not. I agree there are risks involved. In the documents I define the abbreviations and the terms, so with context the reader could check. But the point is that it is an issue.

I can see how to create multiple glossaries, and how to create multiple digests for a single definition, but that's not the issue.

Is there a way to give an abbreviation multiple definitions and display them in the glossary?

For example:

```
E
    EMP
        Engineering Management Plan
            (definition of term)
        Environmental Management Plan
            (definition of term)
```

Comment: Aren't abbreviations supposed to be unambiguous? If AB is used for both *atomic bomb* and *air base* in a book about war, the only way a reader can distinguish between the two in to click on the link in PDF. And if they have a  paper version, they are essentially doomed.

Comment: @andselisk I think the problem is created by two different sources using the same acronym for two different things. If he then intends to cite both sources using the provided acronyms he runs into this problem. If he can discard neither as unimportant to his discussion he is stuck with both.

Comment: I think I would probably resort to appending the abbreviations. Say if TMS as "Train Management System" comes from "Jones" and "TMS" as "Traffic Management System" comes from "Smith" I would redefine them as TMSJ and TMSS and explain in my document the reason for this. Anything else is going to be troublesome as @andselisk pointed out.

Comment: Edited question to add further info (& remove "rant"). @Plergux, I think that may be what I have to do. At the least, multiple abbreviation definitions would cause issues with the `long-short` formatting - which definition should be displayed. Thanks for your understanding